# How to Find "Cannot find the correct chromedriver for chrome version 121.0.6167.185"

Tags: visual-studio, selenium-chromedriver

I have noticed the the latest chromedriver version is 121.0.6167.85
The last 2 digits on the version of chromedriver has a .185 and not .85

When I run my C# selenium script I get the following error: Can not find chromedriver for currently installed chrome version Where can I find the chromedriver for chrome 121.0.6167.185? The latest chromedriver version is 121.0.6167.85. I get the following error message in Selenium.

[System.InvalidOperationException: 'session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 116
Current browser version is 121.0.6167.185 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe (SessionNotCreated)'
]

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, and had no solve... :-/
Did you reach some workaround?

Comment: Yeah me too ! Session isn’t created error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error message says: -

The error message indicates that the `ChromeDriver` version (121.0.6167.85) only supports Chrome version 116, while the currently installed Chrome version is 121.0.6167.185.

***Solutions***

you have two choice:

- One is to upgrade the `ChromeDriver` to a version that is compatible with the current Chrome version `121.0.6167.185`
- Second you can try to downgrade the Chrome version to one that is supported by the current `ChromeDriver` version

Comment: Thanks, there is no version Chromedriver for my current chrome. The latest Chromedriver version is (121.0.6167.85). The last 2 digits should be .185(chromedriver) and not .85 (My Chrome). Both are the latest.

Comment: This is mentioned in the error you posted.  `This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 116`

Answer (score 1):

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

you find all new version of driver